# PLSQL procedure compare two tables to see difference with different date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, compare, procedure

I have two data table provided from different company. My main goal is to compare those two tables to check if there's any difference(ideally all the data should be same).

so my first table format is like this:(just example)

```
companycode     ||  BOOK    ||    DATE                  ||  Amount  ||   
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   06/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   09/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   10/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   11/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   12/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   13/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   16/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   17/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     

---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

First table looks like this as you can see only difference is the date. It's every business day to check to see if amount actually changes.

My first query

```
select companycode, book, date, Amount from al_ext_impact_recon
```

Second table

```
companycode     ||  BOOK    ||    DATE                  ||  Amount  ||   
--------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   28/02/2015 12:00:00 AM || 23679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   15/03/2015 12:00:00 AM || 24679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   10/04/2015 12:00:00 AM || 25679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   12/05/2015 12:00:00 AM || 26679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   11/06/2015 12:00:00 AM || 27679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   13/07/2015 12:00:00 AM || 28679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   16/08/2015 12:00:00 AM || 29679000     
 abcd           || DTCA     ||   17/09/2015 12:00:00 AM || 30679000   

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Second Table, In the other hand only keeps the record when the Amount changes.
Therefore the date is not consistent.

Second query

```
  SELECT COALESCE (sx.a, ps.b) AS companycode,
         pc.profit_centre_mnemonic AS book,
         ps.intended_sd AS date,
         SUM (ps.projected_position + ps.actual_position) AS amount
    FROM ay ps
         INNER JOIN al_profit_centre pc
            ON ps.profit_centre_id = pc.profit_centre_id
         LEFT OUTER JOIN al_raw_stock_xref sx
            ON     ps.stock_mnemonic = sx.stock_mnemonic
               AND sx.stock_code_type = 'ISIN'
   WHERE ps.position_type IN ('P', 'X')
GROUP BY COALESCE (sx.b, ps.a), pc.profit_centre_mnemonic, ps.intended_sd
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

So basically what I want is check only on the date of the second table to do the comparison. and do something like Intersect to see the difference. What the best approach to do this?

Comment: I forgot to add second query.

Comment: You are probably looking for SQL [`minus`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries004.htm#SQLRF52323) operator. Any PL/SQL solution is likely suboptimal.

Comment: I will try to explain best as I could. So the first table is there and the feed data always feed the data even if the Amount doesn't change. Therefore, Date is every single day except for weekend. However, second table with similar data, it only inputs to this table when there's change in Amount with same companycode. 


 So my goal is to output to third(result table) with only the difference show.

Comment: So for example, I have first table March 23rd 2015 and Amount of 23000 and stay 23000 until March 25th 2015. But second table has March23rd 2015 Amount of 23000 and the next record is April.1st with Amount 43000. If I do minus with what I have now, It will return March 25th 2015 as a different but it should not treat as different because Amount didn't change, just didn't show on second table.Because second table only gets input when there's amount change. I hope this explains it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this approach. First of all I "redesigned" your first table so the query only returns records where amount was changed. I did this using analytic LAG function. Now the both tables have same logic and structure and you can use MINUS on them.

```
select * from onchangetable 
minus
select * from (
select companycode, book, curdate, amount from (
select companycode, book, curdate, amount,lag(amount,1,0) over (order by curdate) as amount_prev  
from alldaytable
) where amount!=amount_prev) ;
```

Probably you will need to do MINUS in both ways: onchangetable minus alldaytable, alldaytable data minus onchangetable.

Take a look to sql fiddle example
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5db65/1

Answer (score 0):

Your two example tables would be a lot better if there was some overlap in their time periods. However, if I understand you correctly, table one has an entry for every day (less weekends) and table two has entry only when amount changes.

If so, this query should make table one look like table two:

```
select  companycode, Book, Min( DATE ) as Date, Amount
from    table1
group by companycode, Book, Amount;
```

Now compare using any number of methods, e.g. MINUS or outer join looking for NULL in outer field.